# I am a newbie in bitcoin and want to mine bitcoins

Tags: blockchain, mining-pools, asic

Hello greetings to everyone, I am Ravindra Barthwal from India and now i want to mine bitcoins but i don't know where to start even i search many times on google and everything goes away from my mind.

I have $2000 in hand and a internet connection of 2mbps, having a block chain account so i want to know from you that now i want a asic machine to mine bitcoin. which one is the best under my pocket and how to setup the machine and what othet things will required by me. Please help me .

Answer (score 1):

None of those that I know of and would be profitable are available for that money. I bought a miner from [KNCminer](https://www.kncminer.com/) a year ago and it was worth 4700$ shipping included. It is a 280GH/s miner and it is producing about 0.2 Bitcoins/day. Those are 10$/day, visit KNC and check the prices AND availability.

You have USB ASIC miners and the like, but I don't think they are profitable at the actual difficulty. I would rather recommend buying 2000$ in bitcoin right now and wait for the raise of price. Then use those coins to buy a miner :-). Bitcoin is in its lower values right now, it may go down a little bit or it may go up, but I think it is a better investment buying bitcoins than buying a miner right now.